# What can be the reason for @font-face failing to work?

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have a simple example, where for some reason definition of *@font-face* will work only for **Chrome** and fails to work in **FireFox, Safari and IE**:

https://jsfiddle.net/d8e6xz7e/1/

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="original-font">
    This is the original font
  </div>
  <div class="bold-font">
    This should be bold! But it is not in IE, Safari and FireFox
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lucida Bold Italic';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: local('Lucida Sans Unicode'), local('Times New Roman');
}

.original-font {
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
}

.bold-font {
  font-family: 'Lucida Bold Italic';
}
```

According to the specification (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) it should be supported for the modern browsers. That is why, I suspect that there is something missing in the css definition.

Would be grateful for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most likely confusing a *font face* with a *font family*:

- "Lucida Sans Unicode" is a **font family**
- "Lucida Bold Italic" is a **font face**

In short, a font family is a group of font faces.

@font-face declares a font face joining some custom family. `src` is the path to a font face file, and that is likely where the problem is:

> src: local('Lucida Sans Unicode'), local('Times New Roman');

That's two *font families* being used as the src of a *font face*.

Presumably Chrome handles this easily made mistake and uses the 'normal' font face from the family whenever it spots that this has happened.

So, what you probably meant was this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyBoldFont';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: local('Lucida Bold Italic'), local('Times New Roman Bold Italic');
}

.bold-font {
    font-family: 'MyBoldFont';
}
```

Whenever the text is bold, italic *and* uses .bold-font, you'll see your custom font face show up, like this simple example:

```
<b><i class='bold-font'>Hello! I'll be Lucida/TNR</i></b> and this will be something else.
```

[Here it is as a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/d4g97h0c/)

Comment: maybe you would also have ideas related to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41147727/how-to-add-font-weight-property-inside-a-font-definition-for-the-fallback-font

Answer (score -1):

```
@font-face {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
   src: url(font.woff);
}
```