# How to add font-weight property inside a font definition for the fallback font?

Tags: css, font-face

In our project we use **Fira Sans Bold** for thickening text segments. As a fallback we would like to use **Lucida Sans Unicode** with *font-weight* set to **bold**.

However, we run into a problem that we need to pre-set *font-weight* property for **Lucida Sans Unicode**.

What are possible ways to do this?

We tried @font-face.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lucida Bold';
  font-weight: bold;
  src: local('Lucida Sans Unicode');
}
```

However, the problem is, while using **Fira Sans Bold** we rely only on the font-family and do not use any other other ways of thickening the font, such as font-weight:bold, strong, b, etc. This is insufficient for the @font-face (I raised the question over here: [What can be the reason for @font-face failing to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145790/what-can-be-the-reason-for-font-face-failing-to-work/41146312#41146312))

Would be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: If the font "Fira Sans Bold" is not actually bold by itself, then the name is not a very good name. With a name like that, I would expect the display to be the same whether you used font-weight:bold or not.

Comment: Anyway, more in general, the answer is no. You cannot have a fallback font with different other sub-styles than the main font. There is no such thing as `font: [[medium 'Arial Black']], [[bold 'Arial']]`.

Comment: Same problem as [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145790/what-can-be-the-reason-for-font-face-failing-to-work/41146312): `Lucida Sans Unicode` is a *font family*. `Lucida Sans Unicode Bold`, a font face, is probably what you need here. Declaring font-weight will **not** synthesize a face or select from that font family.

Answer (score 0):

**Declaring font-weight/ font-style etc only affects which text 'matches' a @font-face rule.**

As a font face is either bold or it isn't, declaring `font-weight:bold` won't force it to become bold. It'll just make it show up whenever your *text* is supposed to be bold.

Presumably the text that uses `Fira Sans Bold` is bold when `font-weight` of your text is `normal`. That means you'll want the bold face of Lucida to match whenever font-weight is **normal**, like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyLucidaFont';
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Lucida Sans Unicode Bold');
}
```

*"Whenever my text is `font-weight:normal` and uses `font-family:"MyLucidaFont"` then this font-face is applied"*

Then:

```
font-family:"Fira Sans Bold","MyLucidaFont"
```

This is assuming that you can't change your Fira Sans Bold definition. If you can, then it'd be better to change that instead to make sure it applies whenever your texts `text-weight` is `bold`:

```
/* We don't need to declare Lucida at all if we change this one */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans';
  font-weight: bold; /* That's more like it! */
  src: url('/FiraSansBold.woff');
}
```

Whenever your text has `font-weight:bold` and `font-family:"Fira Sans","Lucida Sans Unicode"` it'll be bolded with a fallback.

Keep in mind that "Lucida Sans Unicode" is a *font family*; a group of *font faces*.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple

```
.supposedly-bolded-text {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans Bold', 'Lucida Bold';
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

would do the trick for you.